# How can i use city name instead of lat and log in OpenWeather API?

Tags: reactjs, api

Good evening!

So basically I want to get weather data from OpenWeather API. Previously I used a different API from this site and there I could use city name to get weather data. Now I want to use a more attractive API from this site where is hourly, daily weather info so this is 100% what I want in my weather app but here I can't use city name? I need to place lat and long inside URL. So how can I do that?

```html
import React from "react";

const KEY = "SECRET";
const city = "London";
const exclude = "daily";

const App = () => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?q=${city}&exclude=${exclude}&appid=${KEY}`
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Weather App</h1>
      <button onClick={fetchData}>FETCH</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: openweathermap.org seems to support city names: https://openweathermap.org/api/hourly-forecast

Comment: please read docs https://openweathermap.org/api/hourly-forecast

Answer (score 4):

That is how One Call API is built.

7 days or `n` days forecast is not directly available for city`[name / id]`. You have to use `lat` and `lon` query params.

---

**Solution:**

You will need to make 2 API calls. Use the `lat`, `lon` value from the first API to call the second API.

*Step 1*:
ref: [Link](https://openweathermap.org/current)

`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city name}&appid={API key}`

This will return current weather data for the city with `lat`, `lon` values.

*Step 2*:
ref [Link](https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api)

`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&exclude={part}&appid={API key}`

This will give the hourly forecast for the previous 5 days and the next 7 days.

---

**Limitation:**

1. You call 2 API's
2. `One Call API` returns an hourly forecast for the first 48
   hours only.

---

**Alternative**

*There is a forecast API.*

1. Hourly forecast for 4 days. [Link](https://openweathermap.org/api/hourly-forecast)
2. 3 Hour forecast for 5 days. [Link](https://openweathermap.org/forecast5)

Answer (score 2):

OpenWeather has access to data by name and/or geographic coordinates (lat/lon):

name:

```
api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city name}&appid={API key}
```

geo:

```
api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&appid={API key}
```

You can find the docs [here](https://openweathermap.org/current#name)

Comment: Basically i wan to use One Call API, I updated post so u can check my code

Comment: and i get {cod: "400"
message: "no location specified"}

Comment: You could use an [api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview) to get the name of the city. Maybe check that url is the correct one as well in your code.

Comment: So basically firstly i need to get lat ang long from city what user type then make another fetch for weather info because i can't use city name in One Call API?